# Can someone advise on DL380 G5 RAM, what is the difference between these DIMMs?

Tags: memory, ecc, hp-proliant

I have 3x DL380 G5 servers that were second hand retired ones. One of the servers, I populated with 4x 4GB DIMMs, and 4x 1GB DIMMs.

Everything was working away merrily, and I decided to purchase some more 4GB DIMMs for one of the other servers. I took all 8 of the 4GB DIMMs, and put them into one of the servers, and I got error messages in POST regarding unsupported DIMMs and differing DIMMs in each bank. I removed the new DIMMs to start with and stuck with the 4 known good ones.

I managed to find that the original 4 DIMMs I had, were of 3 different part numbers. The two that are the same part number are showing as unsupported DIMMs in this server, and do not even work in the server they were originally working in.

Point is, I have 2x KTD-WS667LPQ DIMMs which are now showing as unsupported. As far as I am aware, these are correct as they are PC2-5300F ECC fully buffered.

The other two models I have are KTM5780 and KTH-XW667, which are also PC2-5300F ECC fully buffered DIMMs - these are working ok. Is there some difference between the models that cause the KTD-WS667LPQ ones to now be unsupported in this server?

The new DIMMs I purchased are Samsung M395T5163QZ4, which again are reported as being PC2-5300F ECC fully buffered, yet these do not work either.

Am I missing something truly obvious, as as far as I can tell, all 8 should work just fine.

**EDIT** Page 5 of [this](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04282492.pdf) document shows memory compatibility

Comment: Duplicate of: http://serverfault.com/questions/751304/advice-on-dl380-g5-ram-and-why-the-dimms-i-have-arent-supported

Comment: I asked the question on both sites, as I wasn't sure which was the more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/570004/why-wont-my-dell-server-use-ibm-ram?rq=1), I decided to get the BIOS on the machines updated, and things seem to now be working as expected.

Quite probably due to different ranking/banking layout on the DIMMs, which the BIOS update introduced added support for.